# How to use javascript to query database and put values into an array

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

Context: I have an html page which contains a search bar. This search bar offers autocomplete suggestions based on a locally stored variable which is an array. I can manually enter whatever into that array and it works, but I need to update that array dynamically. I want to use a script within that page to query an SQlite3 database.

This database has one table titled **products** and in that table there are 3 columns; **product_name**,**product_cost**, **vendor**.

I would like to `SELECT product_name FROM products` and then put all of these product names into an array.

I have been stuck on this task for what feels like forever, so any guidance at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should not directly access your database from the frontend. This would be a huge security issue. You need to write some backend code that gets the data from your database and make a call to your backend to get the data.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that makes sense. For context, I am using Django for this project. As it stands, I have a python script that pulls the data from the database and formats it correctly, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to call this python script from the java script within my 'index.html' file

Comment: Request it from your backend with fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API